# How to send data from React form to Django backend server without getting the Unsupported media type error?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

React newbie here, I am trying to create a simple form in React for my backend based on Django, and I keep getting the error `415 Unsupported Media Type`.  My backend is not getting the data sent at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    fetch("http://192.168.0.133:8000/createrfq/",
      {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
          "content_type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.value),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default NameForm
```

Comment: you should post the django view code here

Answer (score 0):

I think the content type specification (`content_type`) is wrong, you should try with:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  console.log(this.state.value);
  fetch("http://192.168.0.133:8000/createrfq/",
  {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.value),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
```

}